# The group $O(n,n,\mathbb{Z})$ and its properties.

Tags: group-theory, string-theory

While reading "String Theory" by Becker$^2$, Schwarz I encountered a group called $O(n,m,\mathbb{Z})$, which is a group of symmetries of the bosonic/heterotic strings compactified on a torus. I would like to learn some more details about this group, like its relations to other groups and isomorphisms. Where can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there is a large literature on integral orthogonal groups, which are a special case of *arithmetic groups*; a good start is perhaps 
[this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143543/algorithm-to-compute-the-integral-orthogonal-group), which discusses algorithms to compute such groups, but also gives more background, e.g., to quadratic forms over the integers. Concerning isomorphism theory the following article might be helpful:
[Isomorphism theory for orthogonal groups over arbitrary integral domains](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869378901473).